# Trying to understand the difference

Tags: excel, vba, infinite-loop, lowercase

I hope nobody will be offended by me asking a question about a *working* code. I was told, however, SO is also for learning so I hope this will be fine.

What I want is to try and understand the difference between two codes I wrote, one working, one failing.

This code is a failing version:

```
Sub Lowercase()
Dim Seq As Range
Set Seq = Range(Range("A2"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
    For Each cell In Seq
    cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

It does put things in lowercase just fine, but it loops forever until I close or minimize Excel.
Thinking on an older code I changed the code to this:

```
Sub Lowercase()
Dim Seq As Range, v As Variant
Dim L As Long, i As Long
Set Seq = Range(Range("A2"), ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell))
  For Each cell In Seq
      v = cell.Value
      L = Len(v)
      For i = 1 To L
          cell.Value = LCase(cell.Value)
      Next i
  Next cell
End Sub
```

This works fine (bit slow but okay) nor do I understand why.

The files I am trying to convert look like (The A2 row tends to go on for 600 to 1200 characters):

[image]

However, I still call all cells and I am not sure why giving the cell a value it actually stops looping. As, but I am sure I am wrong, I have the feeling I still did not change the "For each cell / next cell" part of the coding.

EDIT: It has to do with a faulty use of xlLastCell for my worksheets as that was not the last cell in Row 2. In the second code a value could hit 0, whereas in the first not. The code had to be altered to use a different method to find the last cell.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Your first version works fine for me, with no infinite loop (and your second version seems pointless). Can you please make a reproducible example (one that also explains the layout of the sheet)?

Comment: Comparing your two versions, it seems that there must be at least one cell with the property that `Len(cell.Value) = 0` but for some reason `LCase(cell.Value)` fails to return. I have no idea what would cause this. Circular references? Something weird with volatile UDFs? Corrupt workbook? Until you make it reproducible, there isn't much to go on.

Comment: Edited to show a sample of the Excel sheets. The first codes gives me a the "blue cirlce of thought" with several files for me, so it is reproducible for me. Perhaps I am misinterpretating what you mean with "reproducible" though. I am unfamiliar with terms like 'volatile UDF'.

Comment: I run your code with 600+ cells in row 2 containing upper case letters, and it runs instantaneously, with no infinite loop. By reproducible -- how can someone start with a blank workbook and reproduce the bug? You are running code on existing files. Can you reliably reproduce it on brand-new workbooks? If not -- there is something about the files that the bug appears in, something crucial which you are not telling us (because perhaps you don't know what it is). For example -- is there any other code, perhaps some even-handlers?

Comment: Oright, I apoligize. Did not think that through apparently, I can not reproduce the macro on a clean new worksheet. This macro is part of a few other macros to convert non-office files to excel files in a certain format. The are converted lovely with all their codes untill I added this new macro. Perhaps it has to do with some of the other Macro's involved, should I edit the original post to contain them all (not familiar with the term 'even-handlers') ?

Comment: It couldn't hurt to post them (if my guess of an answer doesn't help).

Comment: Are all of the cells you want to modify in row 2? I think that you are grabbing a larger range then you should be. Maybe `Debug.Print Seq.Cells.Count`. It might be a larger range than you realize.

Comment: They are all in row 2. Does xLastCell not go to the last cell that has content in it? Like Ctrl+Shift+End does?... You know it could be that perhaps therefor it continues whereas in the second code it stops as Len(cell. value)=0 is found in the row below?

Comment: If there are any cells with data below row 2, you will grab those rows as well

Comment: Well now I feel dumb, so because my cell.value = 0 could happen in the second coding it actually stopped unlike in the first code. Solved why it didn't work then. Though, I don't understand why with a clean worksheet it does work... still cells below it. Anyways, I am going to adjust my code. All cells in the row have data so I will make your code a little easier, but many thanks.

Comment: @GMV note that the loop doesn't stop, it's just much faster to check the length of the cell value than to write `LCase(cell.Value)` into it. You should check what the `xlLastCell` returns to you in the worksheets where it doesn't work, for example using `ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Address`

Comment: @arcadeprecinct That comment confuses me as I have not used "" in my code... Nevertheless it is solved due to the fact that xLastCell was wrong to use by me. My mistake.

Comment: @GMV sorry, used `""` instead of `LCase(cell.Value)` because that's effectively what happens when the cell is empty and I was too lazy.

Comment: Ah yes, as I wrote in the lastest Edit (of the original post) it just looped forever as it never had a stop / 0 condition. In the second odd coding it worked as Len(v) = 0 would occure. For my particular case I could even trim the code of @John_Coleman as it now simply finds the proper last cell and all of them are full, so I do not need the Ïf Len(Cell.Value) > 0 part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be some sort of weird interactions (between what, I don't know) going on with your spreadsheet. The following won't reveal what those interactions are but might suppress them. Also, your code has the effect of replacing any blank cells in the range by strings of length zero. I can't imagine that there is any point to this, so I through in a guard against it. I also grabbed the last used cell in Row2 in a more reliable way:

```
Sub Lowercase()
    Dim Seq As Range, Cell As Range, LastCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set LastCell = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft) 'last cell in Row 2 with data, assuming that not all cells in row have data
    Set Seq = Range("A2", LastCell)
    For Each Cell In Seq
        If Len(Cell.Value) > 0 Then Cell.Value = LCase(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: That improves it, but now the mouse pointer flickers as he runs the whole set of Macro's. Let me update the codes on top.

Comment: @GMV   If the macro is being called in a loop -- perhaps you could move `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` etc. from this sub to the caller.

Comment: @GMV See if the minor tweak to the code helps. In terms of your edited code -- `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` etc. could be moved to `RunAllMacros`

Comment: @JohnColeman I think the check if `Len(...)>0` is the important part. It speeds the code up by a factor of about 50 for me (if the cells are empty, of course)